# What metals dampen magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, special-materials

What types of metal dampen magic? I've heard of lead and gorgon's blood stopping teleports. What other metals block magic effects such as fire, ice, lightining, etc.?

Comment: You mean lead, right, not copper? See: https://mobile.twitter.com/kandidkerry/status/894566900180688896

Comment: ahh, yeah. Sorry wasn't quite  sure.

Comment: Feel free to add the twitter link to your question, it might make it a better question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### There are no specific metals named, besides lead

A number of spells (Detect Evil and Good, Detect Magic, Detect Poison and Disease) have this exact wording in them:

> The spell can penetrate most barriers, but it is blocked by 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt.

Message has similar wording:

> Magical silence, 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood blocks the spell.

Detect Thoughts can pierce up to 2 inches of metal:

> The spell can penetrate barriers, but 2 feet of rock, 2 inches of any metal other than lead, or a thin sheet of lead blocks you.

Thus, there no named metals for the purposes of blocking magic: lead is the best, and every other metal is equivalent. However, metals mostly block detection and communication spells--there is no metal that inherently blocks damaging effects like fire and ice. You could get full cover behind a wall of metal, but then it's the full cover protecting you, not any property of the metal.